# How to make a variable visible from different trigger context?

Tags: apex, trigger

I've a variable declared at the beginning of my Trigger. 
Now (after the variable declaration) I've an .isBefore and an is.After contexts , and I'd like to retain variable value in both contexts, but, debugging the value at the end of .isBefore it has the expected value, losing it when .isAfter fires.  (while I need its value in .isAfter)

How could I retain the variable value in every context of my trigger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Borrowing from the most common trigger pattern, I think you'll need to use a helper class to achieve this.

**Trigger:**

```
trigger ObjectTrigger on Object (before insert, after insert) {

    ObjectTriggerHandler handler = new ObjectTriggerHandler();

    if (Trigger.isBefore) {

        handler.beforeInsert(trigger.New);

    ) else if (Trigger.isAfter) {

        handler.afterInsert(trigger.New);   
    }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public with sharing class ObjectTriggerHandler() {

    private static Boolean isBefore = false;
    private static Boolean isAfter = false;

    public void beforeInsert (List<Object> newList) {

        // Before insert logic goes here, check isBefore for recursion protection
        if (!isBefore) {

            // Set flag to true to prevent recursion
            isBefore = true;

            // Now perform logic
            doStuff();
        }
    }
    public void afterInsert (List<Object> newList) {

        // After insert logic goes here, check isAfter for recursion protection
        if (!isAfter) {

            // Set flag to true to prevent recursion
            isAfter = true;

            // Now perform logic
            doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices) is a great article on trigger best practices & frameworks.

Answer (score 6):

A trigger is similar to a class, even allowing static variables within the trigger body. However, static variables in a trigger are reset before each call, and therefore are not truly static (the "static" effect is ignored for variables in trigger bodies).

Therefore, to retain a value across trigger events, such as before insert and after insert, you need to use a class to store that data.

The class:

```
public class A {
    public static String value;
}
```

The trigger:

```
trigger B on X (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore) {
        a.value = 'Hello World';
    } else {
        System.assertEquals('Hello World', a.value);
    }
}
```